# How can I popup an aspx page using Extjs Popup window

Tags: extjs

I need to popup an aspx page in a Extjs Popup window.For popup I am using `Ext.Window`.

Can someone help me how can I popup an Aspx page using `Ext.Window`?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `iframe` to the window.  Here's an example derived from something i did recently:

```
Ext.define('App.view.myWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    title: 'My Window',
    xtype:'myWindow',
    itemId: 'myWindow',
    width: 1500,
    height:800,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'box',
            itemId: 'iFrameInWindow',
            title: 'IFrame',
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'iframe',
                src: 'about:blank'
            },
            flex: 1
        }]
    }]
});
```